# Can I make a bus of buses in Xilinx ISE?

Tags: xilinx

I know how to add a bus to wires in xilinx.
Furthermore, I made a bus to another buses. Now I'm stuck with adding a bus tap correctly. How can I do it?
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I heard that with Xilinx, it's impossible.